# DOMContentLoaded and click event don't occur

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I have a spring boot application with thymeleaf.

My index page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html th:lang="${#locale.language}">
    <head th:replace="fragments/head :: head"/>
    <body>
        <div th:replace="fragments/topmenu :: topmenu"/>

            <main class="container" id="main" role="main">

                <div th:replace="fragments/searchads :: searchads"/>

            </main>

            <div th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer"/>
            <div th:replace="fragments/script :: script"/>

    </body>
</html>
```

In searchads fragment, I have an input box with a button.

```
<form class="row row-cols-lg-auto g-3 align-items-center" id="searchAdsForm">
  <div class="col-12">
    <label class="visually-hidden" for="itemToSearch">Item to search</label>
    <div class="input-group">

       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="itemToSearch" id="itemToSearch" placeholder="What do you search?">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-12">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

Js part of this fragment

```
    <script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            console.log("DOMContentLoaded");

            let searchAdsForm = document.getElementById("searchAdsForm")

            searchAdsForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {

                event.preventDefault();

                let jsonSearchAdsForm = FormDataJson.toJson(searchAdsForm)
                let urlParams = new URLSearchParams(jsonSearchAdsForm).toString();
                let url = "/findads?" + urlParams;

                fetch(url, {
                    method: "get"
                }).then(result => {
                    if (result.status != 200) {
                        throw new Error("Bad Server Response");
                    }
                    return result.text();

                }).then((content) => {
                    document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = content;
                }).catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                });


            }, false);

        }, false);

        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            console.log("full load page");
        }, false);

    </script>
```

When I click to search, this controller is called

```
@GetMapping("/findads")
public String findAdsBy(Model model, @RequestParam(name="itemToSearch") String search){
    System.out.println(search);

    Flux<Ads> ads  = service.findAds(search);

    IReactiveDataDriverContextVariable data = new
                ReactiveDataDriverContextVariable((ads));
    model.addAttribute("ads", data);

    return "fragments/resultsearch::resultSearch";
}
```

Fragment return with js

```
<div th:fragment="adsResultSearch" class="tabsearch">

    <table class="table table-striped">
      <tr>
       <th scope="col">Donateur</th>
       <th scope="col">Titre</th>
      </tr>
      <tr th:each="ad : ${ads}">
            <td><a href="#" th:attr="data-donor=${ad.donor}" th:text="${ad.donor}"/></td>
            <td th:text="${ad.title}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript" inline="javascript">
        console.log("js");
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
            console.log("dom ready");
        });

        document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            console.log("click");
        });

    </script>
</div>
```

It's like the javascript of the fragment return is never running.

I don't see the console log about js, dom ready and click

Edit

When we call load method of jquery,  is loaded, don't seem the case with fetch.....

Any solution?

Comment: `DOMContentLoaded` fires when the whole page has loaded... It does not fire on ajax calls.

Comment: ok but the console.log("js") don't occur... nothing is displayed

Comment: Is it present in `#main` if you inspect?